# Geometric mean in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I am trying to get a geometric mean in rows, the DataFrame looks like this:

```
               PLTRNSU00013 PLSRBEX00014 PLATTFI00018 PLALMTL00023 PLAMBRA00013   PLAMICA00010 PLAMPLI00019 NL0000474351 PLAPATR00018 PLAPLS000016
 2010-07-01          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN  
 2010-10-01          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN     0.968237          NaN          NaN 
 2011-01-01          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN  
 2011-04-01          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN  
 2011-07-01     0.979871          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN      1.00999          NaN          NaN 
 2011-10-01          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN       1.00737         NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN  
 2012-01-01          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN      1.05766          NaN 
 2012-04-01          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN     0.979955          NaN 
 2012-07-01          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN      1.01718          NaN 
 2012-10-01          NaN     0.916302          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN     0.979858          NaN          NaN
```

I did not find any pandas buildin method, so I was using the gmean from scipy
`from scipy.stats.mstats import gmean`
but when called on on row:

```
In [285]:gmean(DataFrame.loc['2015-10-01'])
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-28-e9186c65a04d>", line 1, in <module>
    gmean(DataFrame.loc['2015-10-01'])

  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py", line 305, in gmean
    log_a = np.log(np.array(a, dtype=dtype))

 AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'log'
```

I am getting and exception `AttributeError`
I tried getting rid of the `Nan` with

```
In [287]: gmean(DataFrame.loc['2015-10-01'].dropna())
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-29-e8807696d6be>", line 1, in <module>
    gmean(DataFrame.loc['2015-10-01'].dropna())

  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py", line 305, in gmean
    log_a = np.log(np.array(a, dtype=dtype))

AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'log'
```

I can do it manually with `math` `pow` method, but offcourse it is very inefficient, it works only with scalars.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can do it manually with `numpy`:

```
np.exp(np.log(df.prod(axis=1))/df.notna().sum(1))
```

Output:

```
2010-07-01         NaN
2010-10-01    0.968237
2011-01-01         NaN
2011-04-01         NaN
2011-07-01    0.994817
2011-10-01    1.007370
2012-01-01    1.057660
2012-04-01    0.979955
2012-07-01    1.017180
2012-10-01    0.947547
dtype: float64
```

Comment: thanks, works perfectly well and really fast, comparing to my old math.pow, but I still wonder what is wrong with scipy.gmean

Comment: Just take a look at `gmean` code, essentially same as my code with modification in comment under the other answer. So I'm not sure what's wrong with your `scipy` distribution. Maybe it's time to update.

Answer (score 7):

```
from scipy.stats import gmean
df["gmean"] = df.apply(gmean, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks! If one value is NaN then the result is NaN. Is thee a way to not take them into account like .mean() does? The accepted answer of Quang Hoang allows this.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, why gmean didn't work for you. Have you already checked the datatypes of your columns? are they probably not np.float32 or np.float64?

A solution like proposed by Quang Hoang could work, but I guess only if the product does not produce an overflow. I immagine the gmean takes the logs, sums the results up, builds the average and returns e^(average).

You could of course do this by hand, if you like. Dropping the NAs before (or using an indexer that just ignores them).

So it would be something like:

```
import numpy as np
values= your_df.loc[your_id]
indexer= ~values.isna()
avg_log=values[indexer].map(np.log).mean()
np.exp(avg_log)
```

If you use this method, make sure to use at least np.float64 for the log and mean opreations.

Comment: `gmean` does not work for me as well, probably due to the nan values. Kudos on product overflow, we can modify our answer to `np.log(df).sum(1)` to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

The geometric mean is the nth root of the product of the series. That means it is also exp(mean of logs of values), like so using numpy:

```
df.apply(lambda x: np.exp(np.mean(np.log(x))), axis = 1)
```

Output

```
2010-07-01         NaN
2010-10-01    0.968237
2011-01-01         NaN
2011-04-01         NaN
2011-07-01    0.994817
2011-10-01    1.007370
2012-01-01    1.057660
2012-04-01    0.979955
2012-07-01    1.017180
2012-10-01    0.947547
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the scipy gmean code, it implements `gmean(a)` as `np.exp(np.average(np.log(a),weights, axis))`. This has been noted by other posters here.

Since both `np.exp()` and `np.log()` return dataframes if fed a dataframe, we can let pandas handle nans for us and do:
`np.exp(np.log(a).mean(axis=1))`.